# Issue with laravel and mailgun

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, mailgun

Have a nice time,
I am wondering if there is anyone has the correct steps for using Mailgun with laravel 5.4

Many thanks and best regards,

Answer (score 1):

These are my steps that i follow.

1. first open .env file and bellow code:

   ```
   MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
   MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
   MAIL_PORT=587
   MAIL_USERNAME=uremail@gmail.com
   MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
   MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
   ```

   1. create new account in mailgun.com SignUp if you don't have before.
      After registeration active your mailgun account and click on Domails
      and click on Add New Domail button. then you can see bellow screen.
   2. After add name you can copy domain name and API Key.
   3. Now you have to open services.php and add mailgun configration this
      way :

on `config/services.php`

```
 'mailgun' => array(
    'domain' => 'youremail.com',
    'secret' => 'key-11796c09e58-056a9e975c96dd334da0dd',
),
```

5. Now we are ready to send mail for test so first create test route
   for email sending.

   ```
   app/Http/routes.php   define route:  Route::get('mail', 'HomeController@mail');
   ```
6. Ok, now add mail function in HomeController.php file so add this way

   ```
    public function mail()
   {
       $user = User::find(1)->toArray();
       Mail::send('emails.mailEvent', $user, function($message) use ($user) {
           $message->to($user->email);
           $message->subject('Mailgun Testing');
       });
       dd('Mail Send Successfully');
   }
   ```

   At last create email template file for send mail so let's create mailEvent.blade.php file in emials folder.

   resources/views/emails/mailEvent.blade.php`